# Store textbox input to an array

Tags: arrays

I want to store all the input data of the textbox to an array with unique index number each so I can control them. The problem is that it only assigns zero index for all of them.

```
todoField.addEventListener('keypress', function (b) {

if (b.key === 'Enter' && todoField.value != 0) {
    let newtodo = todoField.value
    task = [newtodo]
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

declear a `function` outside the `addEventListener` and `push` the new items to the `function` that will give them a unique id and store them too.

this is how you should do it.

```
tasks = []; // array decleartion
todoField.addEventListener('keypress', function (b) {

if (b.key === 'Enter' && todoField.value != 0) {
    let newtodo = todoField.value
    tasks.push(newtodo);

} }
```

Now `tasks array` will contain all your tasks.

thank you.